# Ruby/Rails button and search filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've added the Active and Archived buttons to this page for extra filtering.

[image]

The existing search box functionality uses the following js.coffee which calls the controller index to pull the data from the db.

```
triggerSearch: (e) ->
    if searchCompanyTimer
      window.clearTimeout searchCompanyTimer
    searchCompanyTimer = window.setTimeout(( ->
      searchCompanyTimer = null
      query_text = $(e.currentTarget).val()
      el_id = $(e.currentTarget)[0].id
      $.get( "companies", "q[name_cont]": query_text )
      ), 500, e)
```

I have added 2 similar js.coffee methods which set an active flag to true or false depending on which button was pressed.
Here is one of those methods.

```
triggerShowActive: (e) ->
    if searchCompanyTimer
      window.clearTimeout searchCompanyTimer
    searchCompanyTimer = window.setTimeout(( ->
      searchCompanyTimer = null
      $.get( '/companies', {active: true} )
      ), 500, e)
```

here is part of my controller.

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js, :json, :html
  $active_inactive_flag = true

  def index
    puts "params are: #{params}"
    puts "active param is: #{params[:active]}"
    puts "@active_inactive_flag pre any conditions is: #{$active_inactive_flag}"
    $active_inactive_flag = params[:active] ? params[:active] : $active_inactive_flag
    puts "@active_inactive_flag after check on params[:active] is: #{$active_inactive_flag}"
    if $active_inactive_flag.try :nonzero? 
      $active_inactive_flag = true 
    end
    puts "@active_inactive_flag after check if it has a value, else true - is: #{$active_inactive_flag}"
    @companies =
      Company.search(params[:q])
        .result
        .order('created_at DESC')
        .page(params[:page])
        .per(Settings.paginate_limit)
        .where(is_active: $active_inactive_flag)
end
```

here is my index.html.erb file where the buttons and search code is.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Filter By:</label>
            <button class="show_active btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:10px">Active</button>
            <button class="show_inactive btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:10px">Archived   </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Filter by name</span>
                <input class="form-control" id="q_name_cont" name="q[name_cont]" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using a global variable (tried instance and class variables also) in the controller but it's not working as expected. Sometimes the value in `$active_inactive_flag` switches from `false` to `true` or vice versa incorrectly. I don't want to use a global variable but I am at a loss as to how to combine both filter and search correctly. When the page loads we want Active button to be on by default and return active companies. The problem I am having is knowing what button was pressed when the search box is used.

Edit:
Here is an example of what is happening.
[image]
Any direction would be grateful.

Comment: A global in the *controller* means any request can change it, and it’s set for all users. I don’t quite understand why a global is needed (and definitely why it’d be a good idea). Why can’t it be like any other parameter?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that I had used instance and class variable but had the same issue. My last try was with a global variable.

Comment: It’s still not clear what the specific issue is. `triggerSearch` doesn’t send an active parameter, which is falsey. I don’t see any state in the view for storing whether the filter is active (nor is it clear if it’s *supposed* to be persistent). If it’s persistent then you need to save a value on the *client* and always send it in the request.

Comment: yes `triggerSearch` doesn't send an active parameter. I am not sure how to do this from the client side and thought I could fudge it on the server side.

Comment: The same way you do in `triggerShowActive`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dave,

in `js.coffee` added the following:

```
returnActiveInctiveFlag = true
```

and then to the triggerSearch updated to:

```
$.get( "companies", { "q[name_cont]": query_text, active: returnActiveInctiveFlag } )
```

In my new methods updated `returnActiveInctiveFlag` accordingly.

Was really overcomplicating it. Thanks again for getting me thinking in the correct way.